# Start ssh-agent on headless docker host

Tags: docker, ssh, ssh-agent

On my desktop machine I've developed a docker container which clones some Git repository. To provide the credentials I mount my local ssh-agent as it is specified in `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` into the docker container.

Now I want to deploy this docker image on a headless docker host which is running ubuntu. I've created a key-pair for the server which I've also granted access to the Git repository. But when I login the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is not set and no ssh-agent is running. Just forwarding it via `ssh -A` is definitely not what I want.

How do I start the ssh-agent properly to make it accessible to the docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is as easy as executing `eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null` in your shell. But this would start a new agent every time as explained by Jon Cairns in the blogpost [Understanding ssh-agent and ssh-add](http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add/).

To just start it once and get the environment every time use [ssh-find-agent](https://github.com/wwalker/ssh-find-agent).

Clone the repo (e.g. to ~/ssh-find-agent) and add the following lines to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

```
. $HOME/ssh-find-agent/ssh-find-agent.sh
ssh_find_agent -a || eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null
```

This will start the ssh-agent if non is running and set the environment as necessary if an agent is running already.

Now the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` can be mounted to your docker container.